# how do i load a jsp page from a jsp page?

Tags: java, jsp, classnotfoundexception, jsp-tags

I am writing a JSP code which goes like this:

```
<% if(---)
       {----}
   else
       { ---
%>

<jsp:forward page="error.jsp">
<jsp:param name="" value=""/>
</jsp:forward>
<%
  }
%>
```

The error.jsp is in the same directory as the current jsp file still it is throwing "class not found exception". What to do?

Comment: ClassNotFound is not likely linked to JSP-Page not found. Please give full error and code within scriplet (most likely the missing class is used there)

Comment: Try using 'jsp:include' example : - <jsp:include page="error.jsp" />

Answer (score 0):

Not much clear from your question what you are trying to achieve but If you are adding the another jsp page within current jsp page then use jsp:include otherwise if trying to redirect to another jsp page then following could be used.

Use in scriptlet response.sendRedirect in your case as below:

```
<%
   response.setHeader("header_key", "header_value"); 
   response.sendRedirect("your_page_location")
%>
```

Above could be used for external pages as well like "www.google.com"

On the other hand you could use request forward with all old parameters and data from calling page. See below:

```
RequestDispatcher rd = servletContext.getRequestDispatcher("/pathToResource");
  rd.forward(request, response);
```

Also, another easy way could be to submit a form with `action="your_jsp.jsp"` but this should be used in case of form submissions where you are sending some data etc.

Make choice for any of above options on a case basis.

Hope it helps!